# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Tridion Stack Exchange](http://tridion.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Permissions for Items in Translation Jobs?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8518/permissions-for-items-in-translation-jobs)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Do I need a separate license file for Content Porter when using Tridion 2013 SP1?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8551/do-i-need-a-separate-license-file-for-content-porter-when-using-tridion-2013-sp1)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Bundles in Translation Jobs](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8519/bundles-in-translation-jobs)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Catch 'Schedule Publish Phases Separately' event in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 GUI](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/9630/catch-schedule-publish-phases-separately-event-in-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1-gui)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [SDL Tridion Developer Certification](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8573/sdl-tridion-developer-certification)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [XPM "Update Preview" not working](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/9632/xpm-update-preview-not-working)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Multimedia components vs SDL media Manager or any other video hosting tool](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/9715/multimedia-components-vs-sdl-media-manager-or-any-other-video-hosting-tool)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Do I need to configure the broker database as well as the preview database for the XPM web service?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/9591/do-i-need-to-configure-the-broker-database-as-well-as-the-preview-database-for-t)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why does XPM preview have an apparently complete CD web service and broker database?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/9590/why-does-xpm-preview-have-an-apparently-complete-cd-web-service-and-broker-datab)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Event system triggering on Translation manager job start / completed](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/9684/event-system-triggering-on-translation-manager-job-start-completed)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---